# NPM/node-gyp error

Tags: node.js, npm, alsa, pcm, node-gyp

I have tried to install alsa for npm and I run into repeated problems (ref. below). All dependencies have been installed and I am running the latest node.js, NPM and node-gyp versions. Two different fully updated raspbian wheezy systems have been tried out. As I don't have that in-depth knowledge about npm and nodes I was hoping to receive some clues about the underlying problem.

My first idea was that there is a problem with the path files.

Goal-wise I would like to pipe the alsa sound to a streaming server, for that I need to include alsa bindings for npm.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/alsa

Any help highly appreciated!

(some log is missing because I can't paste that much in here, but I cut mainly all pcm.h errors which is pretty long.

```
pi@home-automation:~ $ npm install alsa

> alsa@0.0.2 install /home/pi/node_modules/alsa
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/pi/node_modules/alsa/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/alsa/alsa.o
In file included from ../alsa.cc:3:0:
../pcm.h:16:31: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
 class Pcm : public ObjectWrap {
                               ^
../pcm.h:48:5: error: ‘uv_work_t’ does not name a type
     uv_work_t request;

########### cutted log here #########

    alsa.target.mk:92: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/alsa/alsa.o' failed
    make: *** [Release/obj.target/alsa/alsa.o] Error 1
    make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/node_modules/alsa/build'
    gyp ERR! build error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.35-v7+
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/node_modules/alsa
    gyp ERR! node -v v8.7.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
    gyp ERR! not ok 
    npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/package.json'
    npm WARN pi No description
    npm WARN pi No repository field.
    npm WARN pi No README data
    npm WARN pi No license field.

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! alsa@0.0.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the alsa@0.0.2 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2017-10-16T07_04_32_809Z-debug.log
```

Comment: This seems to be an open issue with the repository which the author has not responded to: https://github.com/xdissent/node-alsa/issues/4. The project looks to be abandoned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read that as well but thought there might be some way to get it working...  Do you recon any alternatives for piping alsa sound to an nom server?

Answer (score 0):

install gcc-c++, that would solve the problem.

Comment: That was the thing that I tried when installing hyperledger components, and found out that c++ compiler would help building missing stuffs dynamically. That solved my case.